# amazing inverse of 0-1 matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics

bonjour,
i am searching about 0-1 symmetric matrices such that in the inverse one has:
positive entries where there was 1
negative entries where there was 0
do you know examples? or results?
thank you

Comment: Without any motivation, this question will likely be closed soon. Please see http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask

Comment: Try matrices related to block designs.  I believe one exists with order 7 and row and column sum 3, but I don't remember if it is symmetric.  With Willie, I recommend providing motivation.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.07.05

Answer (score 2):

Look up symmetric design with polarity. (And do read the FAQ carefully.)